# Taylor's theorem approximation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I'm struggling to determine an estimate for a function (e^-x) using the taylor theorem and getting a truncation error as well. I've tried using the series function but that doesn't let me apply a=0.

Comment: Is this a question about how to use the software *Mathematica*, the topic for this site?

Comment: And what is a??

Comment: I am to find an estimate of e^-x at x=1 and a=0. In taylor series you usually have f(x)= f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) etc. Yes it is for mathematica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your `a` corresponds to `x0` in the documentation for `Series`.  This calculates a third-order approximation around `x=0`:

```
a = 0;
n = 3;
Series[E^x, {x, a, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To evaluate at `x=1` you need to use `Normal` to get rid of the `O[x]^4` terms, then substitute x->1:

```
Normal[Series[E^x, {x, a, n}]] /. x -> 1.
(* 2.66667 *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!